# WSO2 API Manager JMS error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

In the wso2carbon.log , the following stacktrace keeps on appearing.I am using combination of WSO2 identity server and WSO2 API Manager togother.And now configured custom domain names for both of them. But now the error is being printed out. Is it like should i update the custom domain name somewhere instead of localhost for JMS?

```
TID: [-1] [] [2017-05-14 06:22:19,469]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection} -  Unable to connect to broker at tcp://localhost:5672 {org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection}
org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:130)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:631)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:628)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:628)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:409)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:248)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1] [] [2017-05-14 06:22:19,471] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory} -  Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData} {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory}
javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:361)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:248)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:486)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error itself, you should update `repository/conf/jndi.properties`

Comment: If I have custom domain , should i change every place which has localhost to my custom domain?may be something using find and replace all..

Comment: Better to do that. Otherwise, you might experience hostname validation errors and ports binding to different network interfaces.